# Does Flutter GetX have a length limit on the RxString data type?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am developing an application with Flutter. First of all my GetX Controller codes:

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:keycehennemi/Functions/SecureStorage.dart';

class PaginationController extends GetxController {
  RxString ProductImage = RxString("");
}
```

And the codes I assigned values:

```
paginationController.ProductImage.value = snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["Image"];
```

I noticed something when I printed the value I saved here to the console. Some of the value from the database was not saved, it did not fit.

Value in database: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/key-cehennemi.appspot.com/o/Hearts_of_Iron_IV_oyun_kapa%C4%9F%C4%B1.jpg?alt=media&token=da71c9bb-cc8f-40ae-91d2-355f3f10a8b9`

Saved value: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/key-cehennemi.appspot.com/o/Hearts_of_Iron_IV_oyun_kapa%C4%9F%C4%B1.jpg?alt=media&to…`

[image]

As you can see, the value from the database did not fit in the `RxString`. What could cause this and is it normal? How can I solve this problem?

I need to save the data from the database in the `ProductImage` variable.

Answer (score -1):

Try like below.

Replace this

```
RxString ProductImage = RxString("");
```

with

```
RxString ProductImage = "".obs;
```

And it will work for you.